# Rails DRY RESTful design of API endpoints with filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developming a JSON API with Rails 4.2 which looks like this:

```
GET api/v1/car  => app/controller/api/v1/car_controller#index
GET api/v1/car/:id/installment  => app/controller/api/v1/carresources/installment_controller#index
```

Now i would like to extend these endpoint with filters.

`api/v1/carresources/installment#index`:

- all installments for a specific car during a specific time period
- all installments for a specific car by payment type (cash, mobile money, <- mobile money provider)

`api/v1/car#index`:

- all cars by region
- all cars by dealer
- all cars by loan schema

The way i implemented is the following:

`app/controller/api/v1/car_controller.rb`

```
def index  
   res = []
   if params.key?('start_date') and parms.key?('end_date')
     res = Car.index_period(params['start_date'], params['stop_date']
   elsif params.key?('loanstructure')
     res = Car.index_loan_strucuture(params['loan_strucuture'])
    ....
   end
end
```

Which is working, but not such a nice solution to put completely semantically different  logic behind these `if`-"graves".
It would be possible to create a new endpoint for each filter, but i have the feeling that this bloats the routing and controller structure.

I would also like to avoid these if clauses, because these is also some authorization on the users role  going on -which i skipped showing - which is also done with `if clauses`
Is there another clever way, or should i spent an extra route for each filter, where i then need to copy the whole authorization structure.
Many thanks in advance
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OP I would suggest breaking the filtering code little separately by handling the request.query.params in a filter class.

This filter class helps in de-coupling the code by

1. Allowing validation of the filters which are being passed so you can have a `parseFilters` function which does that.
2. You can use the hashtable which points to

`{('start_date','end_date'): "index_period(params['start_date'], params['stop_date']", etc }`

this will help you to apply the filters directly from the parsefilters.
This will ensure that your code is decoupled and also can be reused in other scenarios.